# NativeScript FloatingActionButton from github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I'm very new to NativeScript. I chose it compared to React Native because I wanted 100% access to native API. I started playing with native plugins and read some tutorials like this one [native libraries](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/using-native-libraries-in-nativescript/)
Now I'm trying to follow the same principle with this plugin [FloatingActionButton](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton)

```js
var app = require("application");
var platformModule = require("platform");
var fs = require("file-system");
var imageSource = require("image-source");
```

```js
function creatingFab(args) {

    var fabMenu = new com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu(app.android.foregroundActivity);
    var fabButton = new com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton(args.object.android);
    fabButton.setButtonSize(FloatingActionButton.SIZE_MINI);
    fabButton.setLabelText("Hello Button");
       
    //fabButton.setImageResource(imageSource.fromResource("logo"));
  
    fabMenu.addMenuButton(fabButton);
    fabMenu.hideMenuButton(false);
    
}
```

```html
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo" class="page">
  
    <Page.actionBar>
        <ActionBar title="My App" icon="" class="action-bar">
        </ActionBar>
    </Page.actionBar>
   
    <StackLayout class="p-20">
        <Label text="Tap the button" class="h1 text-center"/>
        <Button text="TAP" tap="{{ onTap }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-active"/>
        <Label text="{{ message }}" class="h2 text-center" textWrap="true"/>
    </StackLayout>
    <android>
        <placeholder id="fab" tap="fabClick" class="fab-button" margin="15" creatingView="creatingFab"/>
   </android>
</Page>
```

[image: error in emulator]

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: cool stuff - if you want to use something already written using the android native FAB widget there is this plugin https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-floatingactionbutton but I understand the learning approach you're taking. It's where I started when I wrote that article over a year ago :) so keep doing what you're doing and you'll appreciate nativescript more and more. @MarekMaszay answer below might help. If not, the android lib you're using might require you pass an image which it looks like you commented out the line  setting the image.

Comment: @BradMartin, I'm a huge fan of your blog. Thanks to guys like you, this is only my second day of nativescript but I have learnt a lot. I will definitely use you plugin  github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-floatingactionbutton . I have looked into it already. I was just trying to see If I could hook into any native plugin easily.  I'm really amazed at what can be done with NativeScript. I just need to push it to the limit to see how far I can go with it :).

Comment: I have uncommented the line and followed @MarekMaszay advice but still not working. I will continue looking into it.

Comment: Thanks :) feel free to reach out on the forums https://discourse.nativescript.org/ and join the slack channel. Many great devs there that can help with any issue you encounter.

Comment: @BradMartin I have joined the slack channel. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try is as this based on this [http://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/*application*.androidapplication.html#foregroundactivity](http://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_application_.androidapplication.html#foregroundactivity)

```
var fabMenu = new com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu(app.AndroidApplication.foregroundActivity);
```

Comment: I have tried this but I still have the same error. I will continue looking into the docs and the library code to see how to properly initialize it.